# Weak Solution to Conservation Law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

**Problem** Let $u(x, t)$ be a weak solution to the conservation law
$$u_t + [f(u)]_x = 0$$
Prove that, for every fixed $(x_0, t_0)$ and each $ε > 0$, the function
$u_ε(x, t) = u(x_0 + εx, t_0 + εt)$
is another weak solution of the given conservation law.

**My Attempt** I plugged in $u_ε(x, t)$ into the conservation law and after simplifying a bit, I got:
$$u_t(x_0 + εx, t_0 + εt)+[f(u(x_0 + εx, t_0 + εt))]_x=0$$
From here, how do I take the limit as $ε$ goes to zero? Or did I do something wrong?
Thanks for the help

Comment: What does the notation $[-]_x$ mean?

Comment: $[f(u)]_x$ means "the derivative of f(u) with respect to x"

Comment: There's nothing about limits here, I think. The result is true for finite $\epsilon$.

Comment: I see. So how would I show it's a valid solution then? Or am I done with what I have got? Thanks for the help.

Comment: To make a proof, you have to put the candidate function into the LHS, and somehow simplify it to 0 (the RHS). You have made a small slip: you have dropped a $t$-differentiation. The next step is a change of coordinates to $x' = x_0 + \epsilon x$ and $t' = t_0 + \epsilon t$. Then you need to use the known property of $u$. I think this will work.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to write the sub-t. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Generally, any PDE that does not involve the variables explicitly is invariant under shifts of variables. Indeed, the shift commutes with derivatives; hence, any solution of the equation $F(u,u_x,u_t,u_{xx},u_{tt},u_{xt},\dots)=0$ remains a solution after shift.

But perhaps one should be more careful  to make the above rigorous when the PDE is understood in a weak sense. The weak form amounts to saying that for every test function $\phi(x,t)$ we have 
$$\int  \bigg(u(x,t) \phi_t(x,t) + f(u(x,t)) \phi_x(x,t)\bigg)\,dx\,dt=0$$
If we let $x=X+h$, $t=T+k$, and introduce notation $v(X,T)=u(X+h,T+k)$ and $\psi(X,T)=\phi_X(X+h,T+k)$,   the above becomes
$$\int  \bigg(v(X,T) \psi_T (X  ,T ) + f(v(X , T )) \psi_X(X ,T )\bigg)\,dX \,dT=0$$
Which says precisely that $v$ is a weak solution of the same equation, because $\psi$ can be any test function here.